# MySQL : Query and group by values in same column

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a sql table data as below.

```
c_type_id | s_id | value
     1    | 11   | Winx32
     1    | 12   | Domain1
     2    | 11   | Winx64
     2    | 12   | Domain2
     3    | 11   | Winx32
     3    | 12   | Domain1
     4    | 11   | Winx32
     4    | 12   | Domain2
```

How to query and group to get the following result.?

```
countall | platform | domain
       2 | Winx32   | Domain1
       1 | Winx64   | Domain2
       1 | Winx32   | Domain2
```

Comment: @Illidanek it kind of is though :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) countall,
        p.value platform,
        d.value domain
FROM    mytable p
JOIN    mytable d
ON      (d.c_type_id, d.s_id) = (p.c_type_id, 12)
WHERE   p.s_id = 11
GROUP BY
        d.c_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pivot the table to get the platform and domain in separate columns, then you can use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countall, platform, domain
FROM (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s_id = 11 THEN value END) AS platform,
             MAX(CASE WHEN s_id = 12 THEN value END) AS domain
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY c_type_id) AS pivoted
GROUP BY platform, domain
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your table name is 'test1', this would be your solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countall, t1a.value AS platform, t1b.value AS domain
FROM test1 AS t1a
LEFT JOIN test1 AS t1b
       ON t1b.c_type_id = t1a.c_type_id
WHERE t1a.s_id = 11
  AND t1b.s_id = 12
GROUP BY t1a.value, t1b.value
```

Tested on MySQL server v5.5.37

Best regards,
speedbomb